# Cannot figure out how to overwrite files in child theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I'm using the catch-base theme as a parent theme and have the following code in functions.php

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'catch-base';
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I for-the-life-of-me cannot figure out how to overwrite any of the template files through the child theme. I have tried the suggestion on the catchthemes website, https://catchthemes.com/blog/create-child-theme-wordpress/ but just using the same directory structure isn't working.

I've also tried adding this code after the "add_action" function, but it breaks the site and gives an "access denied" error.

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/catchbase-structure.php' );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What am I missing is the producer of this "access denied error". it's PHP or the web server ? And wich file do you want to overwrite with the child theme ? the built-in overwriting workk only with parent theme template files

Comment: I was able to workaround actually replacing the file

Answer (score 2):

The catch-base theme wraps every function in an if statement to make it easy to modify if necessary.

Example....

```
if (! function_exists('function_name')) { 
    /* some code */
}
```

So what I ended up doing was adding this to my functions.php file in the child theme and it overwrote the function and the extra divs that I added showed up!

```
function function_name() {
    /* some modified code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Child themes let you override template files that are loaded via the template hierarchy or `get_template_part` such as `index.php` or `archive.php`.

Child themes cannot be used this way to replace arbitrary files such as CSS files, `functions.php`, files included ussing `require` or `include`, etc

If the parent theme contains functions you want to remove or replace, these are your options:

- unhook the filter or action if it's added in the parent theme ( be mindful that the order things happen in is important, you can't unhook something if it hasn't been added yet! )
- redefine it if the parent theme has wrapped the function in conditional checks ( not always possible, inspect parent theme code to check )
- turn the functionality off if the parent theme provides a setting
- dequeue any enqueued scripts or styles you do not want ( be mindful of order/priority, you can't dequeue something that hasn't been enqueued yet! Order matters! )
- contact parent theme author
- fork parent theme

Sadly there is no generic PHP/WP method to remove and replace an arbitrary PHP function. If there is no mechanism provided for doing it then it can't be done.